# loop over factors and numerics to calculate their means

Tags: r, function, loops, mean, factors

I am trying to create a function that loops over my entire data frame.  If the column is a numeric it will return the mean, but if the column is a factor it will have to do a little more to get the overall mean.  At the moment, I am less concerned about the frequencies for the categories in the factor--I have research reasons for this.  So far, I have been able to cobble some of this together, but I know I am nowhere it needs to be to accomplish this.  Here is my code so far:

```
#basic data frame 3 variables
dat = data.frame("index" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                     "age" = c(24, 25, 42, 56, 22), 
                     "sex" = c(0,1,1,0,0))

mean(dat$sex)
mean(dat$age)

#converting sex into a factor
dat[,3] = as.factor(dat[,3]) 

#working on the if structure to calculate the mean for all of the variables

me_func = function(x){
for (i in seq_along(x)){
if (is.factor(x)==TRUE){
  return(mean(as.numeric(as.character(x), na.rm=TRUE)))
} else {
  return(mean(x), na.rm=TRUE)
}
}
}
me_func(dat)
```

Because I am trying to learn coding with R, I know I am missing a lot.  My intent in the function call is to use the data frame name as the input.  Given when I use this for my research, will have much larger data frames, so listing out the names themselves will be rather cumbersome.  This, also, complicates things because the id variable will have to be ignored to get this correct.

Ultimately, I need the function to return the proper means of 0.40 for the factor variable and 33.8 for the numerical variable.  I need to be able to learn this process as it appears to be important for the data analyses I will be doing in the foreseeable future.  I thought about ColMeans, but this does not get me out of a loop or some type of apply.  The factors would have to be coerced to numerics to do this, and the coercion may provide non-sensical means as R has a tendency to change a 0 to a 2 when it is coerced, or at least, in my extremely limited experience it seems to do this.  I, legitimately, only want the mean for all of the non-id variables/columns for the entire data frame.  Does anyone have any ideas on how this will work? If I have missed a post that does this already, please, feel free to point me in that direction.  Thank you

Comment: The "mean" of a factor is meaning less, because it depends on the numeric score associated with each factor variable, which is arbitrary.  For example, you've coded sex as 0/1.  What does a mean of 0.4 mean?  Nothing.  (Not least because you haven't defined what 0 and 1 stand for (Male and Female or Female and Male?)  So what does 0.4 represent?  Hermaphodite?  I may have recoded the same data but recorded sex using 10 and 1.  In which case my raw data would be 10, 1, 1, 10, 10 - giving a "mean" of 6.4.  How do we interpret the difference between your "mean" of 0.4 and mine of 6.4?  We can't.

Comment: Limey, I understand.  When this is live with an actual data frame, that issue is covered.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `my_func` as a function that gets the mean of a vector (remove the for loop), and then apply it to every column using `sapply`.

Also, as @sindri_baldur pointed out, `is.factor(x)` already returns a logical statement, so `is.factor(x)==TRUE` is redundant.

```
me_func = function(x){
  if (is.factor(x)){
    return(mean(as.numeric(as.character(x)), na.rm=TRUE))
  } else {
    return(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
  }
}

> sapply(dat[,-1], me_func)
 age  sex 
33.8  0.4
```

Comment: Ricardo, thank you.  This does exactly what I want it to do.  The system will not allow me to accept the answer for another 5 minutes.  When it lets me, I will do so.  This is a huge help. Thank you

Comment: You  `==TRUE` part can be skipped